# How to safely expose a computer to the Internet with a public IP

Tags: firewalls, intrusion

Our LAN is configured behind a load balancing router, in turn connected to a modem assigning public IPs to connected devices.

I am required to randomly test the connection effective throughput, bypassing the load balancing router, and this requires randomly to connect a laptop directly into the modem. This means the laptop will be given a public IP, exposing this computer to all possible risks. Testing sessions do not last more than 5 minutes. The computer is running Windows 10 1803.

Are firewalls such as Windows Firewall or Zone Alarm strong enough to keep the computer safe during this tests, avoiding computer remediation each time a test is performed?

Comment: Safe against *what*? What do you need to test? We need a lot more context. One could say that this entire site is dedicated to answering this question, so you are going to have to niche this question down.

Comment: Use a firewall to block all incoming connections. Run anti-malware on the device. Do not connect the laptop to the inner network after exposing it to the Internet without nuking it first.

Comment: @schroeder I have edited my original question. BTW nuking the computer would require re-imaging it to ensure to non compromising has occurred

Comment: Yes, that would be the point of nuking the computer.

Comment: This is an inconvenient solution. I guess a robust firewall with all ports closed would be sufficient?

Comment: It depends on what you are needing to test and what you are needing to expose

Comment: Just downloading a file from a given server and test download speed or run a speed test from speedtest.net. Test computer may have all ports closed as requests are outbound

Comment: As you have no special requirements towards the computer running these tests, you could just use a raspberry pi or similar system, which is easy to nuke and/or cheap enough for just this task.

Comment: Would there be a problem with taking out the hard drive and live booting, or even just installing on a flash drive, some well-tested version of Linux, like RHEL Dev?

Comment: All good suggestions. I wonder how do servers running 24/365 on the Internet protect themselfes......

Comment: @Riccardo you have an example in your own network: load balancers, firewalls, IDS, AV, and network segmentation (and likely a lot of monitoring and detection controls). What you are asking is to bypass all the technical controls you have in order to have a bare connection to the modem to test speeds. So, you either use the controls you already have or you get creative.

Comment: @xorist I have burned Ubuntu on a USB stick and booted from there (after disabling the SATA controller in the laptop. Use your comment as a reply, I will vote for it as the accepted solution

Comment: Wonder why this question got a downvote.... bah!

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the load balance router will induce any delay that would realistically change the result. The bandwidth of the router is without a doubt way larger than your internet connection.

You could just boot a live distribution on the laptop, connect it to the modem, and test *several* times the connection throughput. Save the results, reboot, connect the laptop on the load balance, do it again.

I would be surprised if the router influenced the result more than two average deviations.

Comment: It does. It is configured with multiple "classes" of priority, limitations, etc. The only way to test bandwidth is to unplug the router and hook a PC into the modem.

Comment: Measure it, you will see that the difference is not significant. If it **is** significant, call your technical support and ask them why your load balancer is slowing down the connection.